# Using TSQL for SQL Server, is there a way to quickly limit the rows involved in a query? (And I don't mean rows returned)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**Scenario**

Imagine I have a customer named 'Bob' and he has order millions of items of the last several years.  I want to know the average quantity per order.  However, if I'm scanning more than X number of rows I want to simply stop processing.

**Example**

```
SELECT 
    customers.CustomerName, 
    AVG(orderItems.QuantityOrdered) AS AverageQuantityOrdered
FROM 
    dbo.Customers customers
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Orders orders ON orders.CustomerID = customers.CustomerID
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.OrderItems orderItems ON orderItems.OrderID = orders.OrderID
WHERE 
    customers.CustomerID = 1234 --bob's customerid
GROUP BY 
    customers.CustomerName
```

This result set should return 1 record.  But I'd love to throttle the query so that it stopped running, or blew up if the underlying records scanned hit a certain limit.

**Attempts**

- `Count(*) Over()` just returns 1 (or the number of records returned)
- `SUM(Count(*))` is not allowed
- `Top X` is just based on the return record set (and can become horribly slow in cte's)

**Summary**

What I'm really looking forward is someway to have the query analyzer say 'hey, you're going to need about 1,000,000 records here, and short-circuit the query when it hits the limit.

The example is highly simplified. I may searching across 5 tables, and I would love to know what the count of the underlying recordset is prior to aggregating the data.

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just do count(*)?

Comment: If you really need to do this – which isn't obvious – you might want to look into partitioning the relevant tables into 'current' and 'archived' versions. In the recent SQL Server Enterprise versions, there are handy features for doing this nicely, but otherwise you'd need to implement your own solution (and helping you with that in its entirety isn't a good fit for a single question on this site).

Comment: @Josh Jay, Count(*) will give me the count per customer...I really want SUM(Count(*))...which is not allowed. So, I could write HAVING SUM(COUNT(*)) < @@MAX_ALLOWED_UNDERLYING_RECORDSET.  Basically, I want to limit the cartesian product before aggregation.

Comment: @KennyEvitt-Some customers have hundreds of millions of records, some have a few thousand.  The goal is to allow those with only a few thousand a wider range when querying.  I mentioned this below, but imagine looking at your checking vs. savings.  Checking has 100X as many transactions, and your bank probably limits the range you can query (let's say 'per-month').  Savings, however, probably has a few a month. Why should you have the same 'per-month' restriction that checking has applied to savings.  No need to nit pick the example, just trying to phrase it in non-application specific terms.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly a number of rows, but take a look at the [Query Governer Cost Limit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176100%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> a numeric or integer value specifying the longest time in which a query can run... The query governor disallows execution of any query that has an estimated cost exceeding that value.

Note that this is based on estimated cost, which can be tricky. You'll want to take some time tuning your final value, especially as the cost for the same query tends to rise over time as database tables grow.

Comment: I will definitely check this out and get back to you.  Thanks for the lead.

Comment: This is so close to being what we're looking for.  I'm still playing with it.  OPTION(RECOMPILE) is necessary with this to properly evaluate the cost per query.  Also, the SET can't be done dynamically (e.g. by passing in a parameter like '@allowableCostTime').  Still though, this is a fascinating option.

Answer (score 1):

Why?
Why do you want to stop processing?
The overhead of stopping at a certain number is probably higher than just processing

Even if you are joining across five with sub query or cross apply the problem is the index is lost outside the ()

I suggest you post the actual query if you are having performance issues
Make sure you have the proper indexes and filter early as I did in my answer
Look at the query plan
With 4 joins what can happen the is query optimizer just gets stupid and goes all loop joins

And you don't need to alias to lower case.
Table names are not case sensitive

Now you could only go back so far efficiently if you have an OrderDate
But don't do this if OrderDate is not indexed

If you pull conditions into the join it can help the query optimizer filter early
If you have an index on orders.CustomerID and orderItems.OrderID this should be a very efficient query

```
SELECT customers.CustomerName, 
       AVG(orderItems.QuantityOrdered) AS AverageQuantityOrdered
  FROM Customers 
 INNER JOIN Orders  
    ON orders.CustomerID = customers.CustomerID 
   AND customers.CustomerID = 1234 
   AND orders.OrderDate >= '1/1/2010'
 INNER JOIN OrderItems  
    ON orderItems.OrderID = orders.OrderID 
 GROUP BY customers.CustomerID
```

Comment: Regarding the aliasing...just habit.  We always prefix tables with schema, so I should have added 'dbo.' (or usually it's 'Production.' or something along those lines.  

The question actually pertains to many of our queries...some clients have hundreds of millions of records, some have thousands.  We wanted to easily grant wider ranges query-wise to those with fewer records (e.g. query over a year vs. a month).  

Think of it like looking at your online bank stuff...checking has 100X more transactions, but they both might be limited to the same date range (unfairly).

Comment: We currently limit our queries to a date range of 100 days...no performance problems.  If someone wanted to do a 3 year range, and had hundred of millions of records there are performance problems in our testing (queries take 30+ seconds), but if they have a few thousand records there are no performance issues.  So, in our staging environment there are performance problems for those customers that have large datasets to work with.  So the issue is is that 'it depends' and we'd like to open up the range for those with smaller datasets.

Comment: Then again post a problem query with table design.  There may be a way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Below is one possible solution using an APPLY (I have recently decided I love those things). Note that I coded it to use the 10 most recent orders based on a field I assumed would be called OrderDate.

```
SELECT 
  customers.CustomerName, 
  AVG(orderItems.QuantityOrdered) AS AverageQuantityOrdered
FROM Customers customers
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 10 * 
  FROM Orders o
  WHERE o.CustomerID = customers.CustomerID
  ORDER BY o.OrderDate DESC
)orders
INNER JOIN OrderItems orderItems ON orderItems.OrderID = orders.OrderID
WHERE customers.CustomerID = 1234 --bob's customerid
GROUP BY customers.CustomerName
```

Comment: CROSS APPLY and OUTER APPLY have gotten me through some tough queries so I'll think about that.  It might work, but was hoping for something more automated.  I like it though and will tinker.